SQL Rank function in MySQL version 5.7
I was searching for help to figure out Goals Scored ranking for my hockey database to figure out where a team ranks in the league for the category of Goals Scored. I received some great feedback in the answers here text and had it working great.
Problem is when I went live and uploaded to my web host, they only have MySQL version 5.7 and the window functions only work in 8.0. I have tried other options I saw on this website to rank using variable @rank but ran into issues when I had to JOIN another table of data.
What option do I have to JOIN 2 tables of data and rank the teams in the league based on goals scored?
My initial code that worked using MySQL 8 on XAMPP was
 $sql = "SELECT
    `TeamId`,
    `League Id,
    `GP`,
    `G`,
    (`G`) / (`GP`) `GF`,
    RANK() OVER(
    PARTITION BY `League Id`
ORDER BY
    `GF`) Rank
FROM
    `team_stats`
    INNER JOIN `team_data` ON `team_data`.`TeamId` = `team_stats`.`TeamId`
WHERE
    `League Id` = 0;

I also used the following that worked when I ran it on my current web host MySQL version 5.7 but it failed when I put the sql query into my php code because it is reading as 2 different statements.
SET @rank=0; 
SELECT *, (`G`) / (`GP`) GF, @rank:=@rank+1 AS Rank 
FROM `team_stats` 
INNER JOIN `team_data` ON `team_data`.`TeamId` = `team_stats`.`TeamId` 
WHERE `League Id` = 0 
ORDER BY `GF` DESC;

What would be the best way to join 2 tables and rank the results? Please let me know if I need to add further information as this is all new to me?
I am looking for results that would get me this
Table Results
My goal php results would be this.
enter image description here

Is there any need for the php tag?

Get a new web host, if they only offer 5.7.  It is past end of life and no longer receiving security updates; consider it insecure and upgrade as soon as possible

"they only have MySQL version 5.7..." -- Get a new hosting. MySQL 5.7 reached end of life last year. There's no patching or security anymore. It's a time bomb,

Worst of all, it's clear this hosting is unmaintained. It can go bankrupt, disappear at any time without notice, and you'll lose all data.


because it is reading as 2 different statements

You may combine them to single statement with
SELECT *, (`G`) / (`GP`) GF, @rank:=@rank+1 AS Rank 
FROM `team_stats` 
INNER JOIN `team_data` ON `team_data`.`TeamId` = `team_stats`.`TeamId` 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) AS init_variable
WHERE `League Id` = 0 
ORDER BY `GF` DESC;

Operator := is assignment one, and it sets the value to the variable at the query execution plan building step, before the query execution.

Thanks, this seems to be working but maybe I have a bigger problem with my hosting company because when I upload my file it still does not work and my login system isnt working as well. I guess I will contact them to see what I am doing wrong but again, thanks for the help!

@pimpinhockey Enable error reporting. You should know why it is failing first, then you can reach out to host if you need more resources, etc.
